# Python list json conversion to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list in the below format.

```
['111: {"id":"de80ca97","data":"test"}', '222: {"id":"8916a167","data":"touch"}', '333: {"id":"12966e98","data":"tap"}']
```

I need to remove the data column from above list / json and replace it with key value of the list.

I need to transform it to the below structure.
Desired output:

```
[
    {
     "score":111,
     "id":"de80ca97"
    },
    {
     "score":222,
     "id":"8916a167"
    },
    {
     "score":333,
     "id":"12966e98"
    }
]
```

Any suggestions or ideas most welcome.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Few ideas: `for`-loop, [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop or you can also use a list comprehension as follows:

```
>>> import json
>>> l = ['111: {"id":"de80ca97","data":"test"}', '222: {"id":"8916a167","data":"touch"}', '333: {"id":"12966e98","data":"tap"}']
>>> [{'score': int(e.split()[0][:-1]), 'id': json.loads(e.split()[1])['id']} for e in l]
```

If you prefer to use a for loop:

```py
new_l = []
for e in l:
    key, json_str = e.split()
    new_l.append({'score': int(key[:-1]), 'id': json.loads(json_str)['id']})
```

Comment: You can do that with a single split: `key, json_str = e.split(':', 1)`. In one-liner that may require the walrus operator.